# bokeh: add/remove panels while keeping current panel

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to write a Bokeh application that dynamic adds and removes tab panels in response to events happening in the server. It works, but adding or removing a panel to the left of the active panel causes the active panel to change, because it uses a fixed index for the active panel rather than tracking which panel object is active.

I can mostly fix this by first retrieving the active panel and then setting the `active` property on the `Tabs` object to force it back to the current active panel, but there are two problems with this:

1. It flickers: the browser switches tabs, then switches back again. I've tried using hold+unhold — no improvement.
2. The server architecture docs note that changing properties from both the server and the client is not handled well and not recommended. I imagine this would show up as a race condition where the user selects some other tab but the server then forces it back to the tab it was on, plus the server would have the wrong idea about which tab the client was using.

Is there a better approach?

Some minimal code (to be used with `bokeh server`) to demonstrate the basic issue (does not include the workaround from my second paragraph):

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import Tabs, Panel, Paragraph, Button
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.io import curdoc

def callback():
    if len(tabs.tabs) == 1:
        tabs.tabs.insert(0, panels[0])
    else:
        del tabs.tabs[0]

panels = [
    Panel(child=Paragraph(text='Panel 1'), title='Panel 1'),
    Panel(child=Paragraph(text='Panel 2'), title='Panel 2')
]
tabs = Tabs(tabs=list(panels))

button = Button(label='Toggle')
button.on_click(callback)
curdoc().add_root(column(button, tabs))
```

Answer (score 0):

Working example, with async handler to fix flickering and improve resonsveness.

Made a bunch of changes:

1. contain the application including the `serve()` entry point.
2. fix the problem with lost ordering
3. restore the tab selection after insert
4. button runs on executor; UI updates are now async

Code below:

```
import functools

from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models.widgets import Tabs, Panel, Paragraph, Button
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from tornado.gen import coroutine
import tornado.concurrent
import tornado.ioloop


class BokehExample(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # Needed for run_on_executor
        self.executor = tornado.concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
        self.io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()

        # UI Elements
        self.button = None
        self.panels = None
        self.tabs = None

        # Document
        self.doc = None

    @tornado.concurrent.run_on_executor
    def _execute_async(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Run function on executor
        """
        return function(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def _update_async(self, element, attr_name, attr_value):
        """
        Decouple the GUI update from the calling thread.
        """
        def set_ui_attr():
            setattr(element, attr_name, attr_value)
        self.doc.add_next_tick_callback(functools.partial(set_ui_attr))

    def async_button_handler(function):
        @functools.wraps(function)
        @coroutine
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            rval = yield BokehExample._execute_async(self, function, *args, **kwargs)
            return rval

        return wrapper


    @async_button_handler
    def callback(self):
        active_panel_id = self.tabs.tabs[self.tabs.active].id
        nr_tabs = len(self.tabs.tabs)

        # Insert logic
        if nr_tabs == 1:
            # async version of: self.tabs.tabs = self.panels
            self._update_async(self.tabs, 'tabs', self.panels)

            new_index_of_active_tab = next(i for i, t in enumerate(self.panels) if t.id == active_panel_id)
            self._update_async(self.tabs, 'active', new_index_of_active_tab)

        # Delete logic
        else:
            self._update_async(self.tabs, 'tabs', [p for p in self.panels if p.id == active_panel_id])

    def render(self, doc):
        # Note that the IDs are ascending. This property is used to restore ordering on delete/insert cycles.
        # You can also use other logic for that, for example a dictionary of titles and their relative positions.
        self.panels = [
            Panel(id="1001", child=Paragraph(text='Panel 1'), title='Panel 1'),
            Panel(id="1002", child=Paragraph(text='Panel 2'), title='Panel 2'),
            Panel(id="1003", child=Paragraph(text='Panel 3'), title='Panel 3')
        ]

        self.tabs = Tabs(tabs=self.panels)

        self.button = Button(label='Toggle')
        self.button.on_click(self.callback)

        self.doc = doc
        self.doc.add_root(column(self.button, self.tabs))


    def serve(self):
        server = Server({'/': self.render}, num_procs=1)
        server.start()
        server.io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
        server.io_loop.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    BokehExample().serve()
```

Comment: This looks more-or-less like what I already tried. I tried to test it to see if it has the same flickering problem, but it just gives an error as soon as it starts, and doesn't show anything: `ValueError("expected an instance of type LayoutDOM, got Panel(id='1001', ...) of type Panel",)` (unfortunately the full error is too long to be allowed as a comment).

Comment: Flickering is best resolved by updating the layout as a whole. i.e `tabs.tabs = [p for p in panels if ...` instead of iterating insert or delete operations.

Comment: wrt the error: bokeh version? I have 1.0.4 on python 3.6.7 (ubuntu 64).

Comment: I tried 1.1.0 and 1.2.0. I'll give it a try with 1.0.4 later.

Comment: Let me know. I'll migrate to 1.2.0 at some point and I have these dynamic tabs in my app too.

Comment: The code runs with 1.0.4. I've changed the code a bit to just assign to tabs.tabs (I don't know how to paste it into a comment though), alternatively showing all tabs or just tabs 2+3. There is still flicker if I go to tab 2 then delete tab 1, because that briefly makes tab 3 active before tabs.active is updated. I need a way to atomically set both tabs.tabs and tabs.active.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up regarding 1.2.0. In my app, the flickering is a lot better since I made the button handlers async.  I will share an async decorator in my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I still see flickering. Incidentally, I ended up using dash for this project (which indicates the active tab by name instead of position).